# customer last login date

Tags: magento-1.7, login

Using customised Magento ver. 1.7.0.2, how I display/export customer list with last login date?

I am looking for last login date and never logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach($collectin as $customer){
   $logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
   $lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();
   echo $lastVisited = $customer->getFirstname(). " => ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastVisited). "<br>";
}
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

**[UPDATE]**

To show this result in admin area, I would create a simple admin extension: [learn here.](http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/)

And put above code in controller for quick view, however I want you to understand how MVC works in magento and show desired result in magento way.

Comment: Sorry I am a novice in this, where do I insert this code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends. Where do you want to display the result?

Comment: in the default customer list or in an export with customer listing and the last login and/or no of logins

Answer (score 3):

if you have access to phpMyAdmin, you can run the following query for looking at customers in last login order:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity`
LEFT JOIN `log_customer` on customer_entity.entity_id = log_customer.customer_id
ORDER BY log_customer.login_at DESC
```

or if you want a list of those who never logged in:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity`
LEFT JOIN `log_customer` on customer_entity.entity_id = log_customer.customer_id
WHERE log_customer.login_at IS NULL
```